# How deploy Spring MVC app on remote server via SSH?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, ssh

I wrote small java app with Spring MVC that I run on tomcat. I got VPS and now try to deploy my app on it for remote access to my app. I installed tomcat on server (as I did it right) and now I need to transfer my war on server and run it, but I didn't find any documentation about it. How can I do deploy via SSH connection (as same as I installed java and tomcat)?
Maybe there are some better way to run war app on VPS (not use tomcat)?

EDITED:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /YaPokupay could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/YaPokupay]]
```

my app structure:

[image]

server logs:

```
Dec 20, 2016 7:02:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:25:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 8:50:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /YaPokupay could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/YaPokupay]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JarScannerFactory.getJarScanner(JarScannerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:260)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more

Dec 20, 2016 8:50:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /YaPokupay could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/YaPokupay]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JarScannerFactory.getJarScanner(JarScannerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:260)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more

Dec 20, 2016 8:55:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 8:55:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /YaPokupay could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/YaPokupay]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JarScannerFactory.getJarScanner(JarScannerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:260)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more

Dec 20, 2016 8:55:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 9:01:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 9:01:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 9:01:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /YaPokupay could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/YaPokupay]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JarScannerFactory.getJarScanner(JarScannerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:260)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more

Dec 20, 2016 9:01:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 9:08:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 20, 2016 9:14:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 9:14:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Dec 20, 2016 9:14:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/YaPokupay'
Dec 20, 2016 9:14:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 9:55:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 10:44:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 10:44:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Dec 20, 2016 10:44:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 10:47:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Dec 20, 2016 10:47:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Dec 20, 2016 10:47:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that can include load balancing, build server, repository hook, and many other unnecessary suggestions. Out of all things; I recommend for developers to use local or remote server for development and mitigate unwanted changes from getting its way in production server. You seem to be doing this correctly so far.

I would suggest trying out FileZilla to transfer your files. For advanced users, I usually use ***Secured Copy*** to transfer files:

Download: *`scp [options] <user>@<host>:<path> <path>`*

Upload:   *`scp [options] <path> <user>@<host>:<path>`*

Here is an example to download `ROOT.war` from a server with `centos` as host name.

`scp guser@centos:/home/guser/ROOT.war /c/Apps/`

Comment: Yes, you can configure Protocol option under General tab in Site Manager. To use SSH, please select SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocol as option. Did this worked?

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly! Thank you very much! But I still can't run my app on tomcat.

Comment: Did you copy ROOT.war into your webapp directory and then restarted tomcat? I'm not sure about your VPS settings.

Comment: What do you mean while say webapp dirrectory? After installing tomcat I have such dirrectories on server(Ubuntu): /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost

Comment: Also I found that I need to add some permisions in war file. But I don't know which!

Comment: Try `chmod ugo+r ROOT.war` and then restart Tomcat.

Comment: I  tried to do this
sudo service tomcat7 stop

mvn clean package
sudo cp target/DestroyTheWorldWithPeace.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
#you might also want to make sure war file has permission (`777` not just `+x`)
sudo service tomcat7 start

Comment: And got error while tried deploy my app: error in question after EDITED

Comment: I need more information about what you're doing. I think you're trying to deploy application that is not `ROOT.war`. Did you wanted to deploy `DestroyTheWorldWithPeace.war` on Tomcat server? Try placing the said WAR file in `/etc/tomcat7/webapps/` directory and restart Tomcat.

Comment: I want to run my app with structure (in question) on VPS. When I did it on heroku it was just push to it but on VPS I need to run it on Tomcat in Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I reload tomcat and didn't get any errors but get 404 error while go to my app's url. I don't know why.

Comment: I would suggest sharing us with your URL. In this case, the URL should be: http://localhost:8080/DestroyTheWorldWithPeace/index.jsp

Comment: I tried this variant. Result is the same : HTTP Status 404 - /YaPokupay/  
description The requested resource is not available.